# Integral solve only using

Tags: indefinite-integrals, integral-transforms

How can I solve $$\int \sqrt{1+\cos(6x)} \,dx$$ only using algebraic, trigonometric methods, immediate integrals and integral properties?

Comment: I already use cos(6x) = cos^2(3x)-sin^2(3x) but I can't get the result.

Comment: So, $1+\cos6x=1+\cos^23x-\sin^23x=2\cos^23x$ as in my answer

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Use $$\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1$$

and $$\int\cos mxdx=\frac{\sin mx}m+C$$ for $m\ne0$ and $C$ is an arbitrary constant

Comment: Please disclose the mistake here

Comment: Everything you wrote is correct, so I upvoted. One might add that special care has to be taken where $\cos 3y$ is negative.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thanks for your feedback. I left it to the OP. But, I was expecting the down-voter will pinpoint the mistake within the answer, so that the OP & I also can be benefited

Comment: It would be very difficult for someone to point to a mistake in an answer that has no mistake. Perhaps, hence, the silence.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I definitely see a mistake. The integral should be $\int{\sqrt{1+\cos(6x)}}dx=\int{\sqrt{2\cos^2{3x}}}dx=\sqrt{2}\int{|\cos{3x}|}dx$. @labbhattacharjee's integral really should be of the absolute value of cosine.

Comment: @DavidH, did you notice the 'HINT'? Did I write anything about $\sqrt{2\cos^2x},$ I just left it to the User.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I in fact did not notice the HINT disclaimer. Shame on me for putting words in your mouth. I guess I'll just see myself out. =p